# Board Game in Unity using Photon Fusion

Tags: unity-game-engine, network-programming, photon

I wish to make an online multiplayer board game using Photon Fusion. The basic gameplay involves people clicking shop buttons to purchase things, and a next turn button to pass the turn on to the next player. I would also like to only display certain text boxes to the person current taking their turn.

However, I am really struggling to find a tutorial on how I could make this work. Sorry if this is a dumb question, any pointers would be greatly appreciated. Networking is one of my weakest spots.

I have tried to do research on this (the Photon docs, Youtube, reddit, etc) but almost everything I have found uses Photon's predictive movement and keyboard buttons for fps or parkour games.

Being very new to networking, I am struggling to figure out how to make a scene that uses buttons controlled by different people on each turn and moves a gameObject for everyone.

Answer (score 7, accepted):

## TL;DR

Use `RPCs`, `[Networked]` variables and `OnChanged` callbacks to communicate back and forth between the host and clients.

You can create a `[Networked]` variable holding the `PlayerRef` of the current player with an `OnChanged` callback. When the `[Networked]` variable changes, all players will call the `OnChanged` callback. Each player can then check if it is their turn with `Runner.LocalPlayer`. If it is their turn, only show the buttons and textboxes for that player.

When the player presses the next turn button, call an `RPC` from that player to the host, which will then change the `[Networked]` current player again. The next player will detect this change and show the corresponding UI for that player.

You can either hide the UI for the current player when the next turn button is pressed, you can also hide the during the `OnChanged` callback. It is up to you.

Highly recommend taking a look at the Fusion Imposter game sample. It is basically an AmongUs clone, where each player can complete individual tasks. The UI shown to each player is different, and they collectively affect the network state of the total number of tasks completed. It also uses RPCs to communicate from the client to the host.

Useful Links

- [Fusion Imposter Game Sample](https://doc.photonengine.com/fusion/current/game-samples/fusion-impostor)
- [RPC - Tutorial](https://doc.photonengine.com/fusion/current/tutorials/host-mode-basics/6-remote-procedure-calls)
- [RPC - Manual](https://doc.photonengine.com/fusion/current/manual/rpc)
- [OnChanged - Manual](https://doc.photonengine.com/fusion/current/manual/network-object/network-behaviour#onchanged)

## The (really) long answer

I get what you mean. Most of Photon Fusion's examples and documentation are geared towards games with continuous input. But after messing around with Fusion for some time, here are a few things I've learnt. Hope they could help you in figuring out a solution for your problem.

There are many ways to do one thing, and there is no absolute "right" way to do it. The solution for your problem right now may change in the future when you face another problem, and that's ok. The codebase is living and breathing and changes all the time, constantly refactoring while adding new features. So it is important that you first understand the concepts behind multiplayer networking with Photon Fusion, so that you can find a solution to make things work now, fix bugs, and make decisions in the future if you need to change or try other solutions.

### Concept Overview

In general, anything that is networked can only be changed by the `StateAuthority`. For example only the `StateAuthority` can change `[Networked]` variables and spawn `NetworkObjects`. We can call this the network state.

The network state is synced across all clients, and most of the what the client sees are just responding to changes in the network state. For example, let's say we have a `GameObject` with a `NetworkTransform` component. The `transform` of this `GameObject` is a part of the network state because of the `NetworkTransform` component. If `StateAuthority` changes the `transform.position` of this `GameObject`, since the `transform` is part of the network state, the position of this `GameObject` will also change in all clients in response to the change of the network state. All clients will see the same `GameObject` moving. The position of the `GameObject` is then considered synced across all the clients. If any client tries to change the `transform.position` of this GameObject, nothing will happen because only the `StateAuthority` can change the network state.

For a client to change or influence the network state, there are in two ways to do so in Fusion.

#### 1. Network Input

The first method is via `NetworkInput`. This is most likely what you encounter the most in the Fusion documentation. With `NetworkInput`, clients can influence the `NetworkObjects` that they have `InputAuthority` over. The input is first [collected](https://doc.photonengine.com/fusion/current/tutorials/host-mode-basics/2-setting-up-a-scene#collecting_input) from the client, then it is sent to the host and [applied](https://doc.photonengine.com/fusion/current/tutorials/host-mode-basics/2-setting-up-a-scene#applying_input) during the `FixedUpdateNetwork` loop, updating the network state of the NetworkObject that the client has `InputAuthority` over, and synchronizes the network state across all other clients.

Fusion does this in a really powerful way, with [prediction](https://doc.photonengine.com/fusion/current/manual/network-simulation-loop#prediction) done out of the box so that the client can have instant feedback even if the network state haven't been changed yet in the host.

But the concept is still the same. The network state can only be changed by `StateAuthority`. The network state is synchronized across all clients. Clients may influence the network state of the `NetworkObjects` that they have `InputAuthority` over, but ultimately it is the `StateAuthority` that allows these changes to the network state and synchronizes these changes across all the other clients.

However, like you said, most of the documentation revolves around collecting keyboard input. There is a small paragraph showing [how to poll input with UI](https://doc.photonengine.com/fusion/current/manual/network-input#poll_input_with_ui), but in that context my guess is that this is for mobile games with UI buttons for movement. Not useful for your case with clicking buttons to purchase things and a next turn button.

#### 2. RPC

The second method is via `RPC`. In the [documentation](https://doc.photonengine.com/fusion/current/tutorials/host-mode-basics/6-remote-procedure-calls) you can feel that Fusion highly discourages the use of `RPCs`. I can understand why.

`RPCs` are

- Not tick aligned
- Not part of the network state

Therefore, `RPCs` are not suitable for tick-based simulation games such as fps and parkour games. In those types of games, `NetworkInput` is indeed more than enough in most cases as the player mostly interacts with the world via keyboard inputs and mouse clicks.

`RPCs` not being part of the network state is also a problem. For example, let's say we have `GameObject` in the scene with a `NetworkBehaviour` script but WITHOUT a `NetworkTransform` component. A client can call an `RPC` to change the `transform.position` of this `GameObject` directly in all other clients. Indeed all clients can see this `GameObject` move from its old position to a new position. But if a new client joins the game, the `GameObject` will remain in its old position because (1) the position of the `GameObject` is not part of the network state and (2) the `RPC` is not part of the network state and will only be fired once. The `RPC` will not fire again for new clients joining the game. The position of the `GameObject` is then considered NOT synced across all the clients.

Continuing the previous example, how can we sync the position of the `GameObject` without using `NetworkTransform`? Always remember that the network state can only be changed by `StateAuthority`, which is then synchronized across all clients. One way to add the position to the network state is by creating a `[Networked]` variable storing the position and changing the position of the `GameObject` using [`OnChanged` callbacks](https://doc.photonengine.com/fusion/current/manual/network-object/network-behaviour#onchanged).

-> Client calls `RPC` to `StateAuthority` sending a new `Vector3` position

-> `StateAuthority` receives the `RPC` and changes the `[Networked]` position variable

-> All clients detect that the `[Networked]` variable has changed

-> All clients call the `OnChanged` callback to update the `transform.position` of the `GameObject`

Then the position of the `GameObject` is now synchronized across all clients. The difference is that the `RPC` is used to change the network state, which is then synchronized across all clients, rather than the RPC directly changing the position of the `GameObject`.

For a new client joining the game,

-> New client sets the `transform.position` to the `[Networked]` position in `Spawned()`

Thats all it takes to keep the position of the `GameObject` synchronized even for new clients which did not receive the `RPC`. This is because the result of the `RPC` is stored in the `[Networked]` variable and is part of the network state.

In general, `RPCs` are great if

- The method call does not need to be tick-aligned
- The method call is not called frequently
- The result of the `RPC` can be stored in the network state to be synchronized across clients.

### My Suggestion

Indeed all the documentation on predictive movement and keyboard buttons are not suitable for your case at all. You should highly consider using `RPCs` instead of `NetworkInput`. Your game is not a tick-based simulation, so `RPCs` would work great for your case.

The difficult part is designing the architecture of your game, eg deciding how to store the network state in `[Networked]` variables, and which methods should be called with `RPC` and whether you should use OnChanged for reflecting changes in the clients or use an `RPC` from the host to a specific client.

Just keep in mind that `RPCs` are not part of the network state, and you should find some way to store the result of an `RPC` in the network state. In most cases, clients would call an `RPC` to the host, the host changes the network state, then the clients would act based on the changed network state.

In some rare cases, you may call an `RPC` from the host directly to the client, or very rarely a client to another client. Again, its a decision you have to make, and its ok to change your solution later on if it doesn't work well.

If I were in your situation, I would have a `[Networked]` variable storing the [`PlayerRef`](https://doc.photonengine.com/fusion/current/manual/player#playerref) of the player currently taking their turn. We can call it `_currentPlayer`.

When `currentPlayer` changes

-> Triggers the [`OnChanged`](https://doc.photonengine.com/fusion/current/manual/network-object/network-behaviour#onchanged) callback on every player

-> Each player checks if the `currentPlayer` is equal to their own local `PlayerRef` with `Runner.LocalPlayer`

-> if it is their turn, then show the UI only for that player

```
public class GameManager : NetworkBehaviour 
{
    [Networked(OnChanged = nameof(OnCurrentPlayerChanged))] 
    private PlayerRef _currentPlayer {get; set;}

    // ...

    private static void OnCurrentPlayerChanged(Changed<GameManager> changed)
    {
        changed.Behaviour.OnCurrentPlayerChanged();   
    }

    private void OnCurrentPlayerChanged()
    {
        // If it is my turn
        if (_currentPlayer === Runner.LocalPlayer)
        {
            // show the buttons / textboxes
        }

        // If it is not my turn
        else
        {
            // you may want to hide the buttons and textboxes for other players
        }
    }
}
```

When the buttons are pressed,

-> The player can call `RPCs` to the host.

-> The host can then change the network state, eg. updating the amount of coins a player has or move a game object.

-> The network state will then be synchronized across all the clients, so everyone can see the same game object moving.

```
// Called locally on client only
public void OnButtonPress()
{
    int someDataFromThePlayer = ...; // Whatever data you want to sent to the host
    RPC_OnPlayerButtonPressed(someRandomDataFromThePlayer);
}

// Called on the host only
[Rpc(RpcSources.All, RpcTargets.StateAuthority)]
private void RPC_OnPlayerButtonPressed(int someRandomDataFromThePlayer)
{
    // Do whatever you want here with someRandomDataFromThePlayer and change the network state
    // The data does not have to be an int. Check the docs for the supported types.
}
```

If a player ends their turn

-> The player can call `RPCs` to the host.

-> the host can change `_currentPlayer` to the next

-> All players call `OnChanged`

-> Previous player that had their UI open will close

-> Current player that had their UI closed will now open

```
public class GameManager : NetworkBehaviour 
{
    [Networked(OnChanged = nameof(OnCurrentPlayerChanged))] 
    private PlayerRef _currentPlayer {get; set;}

    // ...

    // Called locally on client only
    public void OnEndTurnButtonPress()
    {
        RPC_OnPlayerEndTurn();
    }

    // Called on the host only
    [Rpc(RpcSources.All, RpcTarget.StateAuthority)]
    private void RPC_OnPlayerEndTurn()
    {
        PlayerRef nextPlayer = ...; // Somehow get the PlayerRef of the next player
        _currentPlayer = nextPlayer; // Triggers the OnChanged below on all clients
    }

    // ...

    private static void OnCurrentPlayerChanged(Changed<GameManager> changed)
    {
        changed.Behaviour.OnCurrentPlayerChanged();   
    }

    private void OnCurrentPlayerChanged()
    {
        // If it is my turn
        if (_currentPlayer === Runner.LocalPlayer)
        {
            // show the buttons / textboxes
        }

        // If it is not my turn
        else
        {
            // you may want to hide the buttons and textboxes for other players
        }
    }
}
```

### Case Study: Fusion Imposter

[Fusion Imposter](https://doc.photonengine.com/fusion/current/game-samples/fusion-impostor)

Although a lot of Fusion's documentation and examples show games with continous input, I found this great example that shows different UI for different players. The UI for different players also collectively affect the network state, which is synced and shown across all players.

This game is basically AmongUs in 3D. Players walk around doing individual tasks while the imposter tries to kill everyone.

It is quite advanced. But here is an overview and my understanding of what is going on when a player presses E near a TaskStation.

1. `PlayerMovement.FixedUpdateNetwork()`

- Checks if player presses E. If so, will call `TryUse()` locally.

2. `PlayerMovement.TryUse()`

- Checks if the nearest interactable is a `TaskStation`. If so, call `Interact()` locally

3. `TaskStation.Interact()` => `TaskUI.Begin()`

- Opens up the UI locally for that player only.
- When the player completes the task, `TaskBase.Completed()` is called.

4. `TaskBase.Completed()` => `GameManager.Instance.CompleteTask()`

- Player calls an `RPC` to the host called `Rpc_CompleteTask()`

5. `GameManager.Rpc_CompleteTask()`

- Called on the host only, it updates the network variable `TasksCompleted`, which triggers the `TasksCompletedChanged` `OnChanged` callback.
- Checks if all tasks are completed. Crew wins if all tasks are completed.

6. `GameManager.TasksCompletedChanged()`

- Updates the total tasks bar UI fill amount on all players.

As you can see, it is possible for each player to have their own UI to do their own thing. Each player communicates back to the host via `RPC`, which changes the network state, which is then synchronized across all clients.

### Summary

Lol I got carried away and seemingly typed a really really long essay.

Here are the takeaways

- Network state can only be changed by `StateAuthority`
- Network state is synchronized across all clients
- Clients can only change/influence the network state via `NetworkInput` or `RPC`
- If your game is not a tick-based simulation, `RPCs` are a great solution
- `RPC` from player to host -> host changes network state -> all players detect change in network state with `OnChanged` and decide on their own what to do with this change locally

Hope this helps!

### References

- https://doc.photonengine.com/fusion/current/manual/network-object/network-object
- https://doc.photonengine.com/fusion/current/tutorials/host-mode-basics/6-remote-procedure-calls
- https://doc.photonengine.com/fusion/current/manual/rpc

*By this all people will know that you are my disciples, if you have love for one another. John 13:35 (ESV)*

Comment: Can you check this question please? https://stackoverflow.com/q/76636644/11131823

Comment: sure I'll have a look later!

Comment: Wow. This is amazing. I wish I had enough reputation to upvote this, because it is one of the most through answers I have ever seen on stackoverflow. Thanks so much! I will continuously reference this whole working on this project.

Comment: Nevermind, just got enough reputation.

Comment: Glad to help! I struggled a lot too when I first started learning Fusion. Highly suggest joining the Photon Discord! It's pretty active with people asking questions and people answering all the time. Might learn a thing or two every now and then.